# what is this: <td width="*%">?

Tags: html, syntax

I found it in some legacy code. Due to the fact that the code in question had more syntax errors than lines and I can't find any reference to it online, I am inclined to think that it is just a syntax error copy pasted onto a dozen different pages, but that said, it does look like it could possibly be some obscure (probably deprecated) valid syntax. The historian in me is curious.

Comment: to clarify, I am asking about the "*%" (the asterisk is not a placeholder, that is literally the character present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk means the "remaining space", but I don't think it is used with percentage

see also
[What is the purpose of setting width equal to an asterisk in inline styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348819/what-is-the-purpose-of-setting-width-equal-to-an-asterisk-in-inline-styles)

Comment: width isn't even an inline style its an attribute. I have never seen or heard of anyone adding that to an attribute.

Comment: @Adrianopolis it is extreeeeeeemly old and deprecated. you can often see stuff like that in wysiwyg generated code

Comment: Ahhhh like old school dreamweaver and ms frontpage? lol. Figures... I've been raw coding for way too many years now. Never use that stuff :o)

Comment: future generations thank you. you have not known despair until you see code generated by an editor edited by someone who does not know html, with 90% of it's html written in string literals, over 10 years and 2 contractors before mine...

Answer (score 0):

width typically consists of a straigh pixel value in the following format `width="80"` or if more responsive table then it may be `width="25%"` but an *% in a td is odd unless there is some custom js or something using it. Even then it still doesn't make sense.